# for and forEach bypass Array property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, javascript-objects

I am digging into this & Object prototype (You Don't Know JS) and I found this tricky thing that blew my mind:

I created a literal Array (JS Arrays are objects) `x = ['foo', 42, 'bar']` and added a property called baz like `x.baz = 'baz'`. Then, in Chrome dev console, just typping **x** will display the following result: `> (3) ["foo", 42, "bar", baz: "baz"]`. If I unfold the "`>`", each value of the array has its own key like:

`0: "foo"`

`1: 42`

`2: "bar"`

`baz: "baz"`

What kind of *JS-object-monster* did I create? For and forEach loops do not count the **baz** property and bypass it.

Help would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It might just be the way the Chrome console gets confused serializing hybrid array-objects.

What you've done is perfectly legitimate and forEach correctly ignores non-standard custom properties in an array.

Comment: "*and added a property `x.baz = 'baz'`*" - well, [**DONT**](https://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/)!

Comment: It's not a monster. It's just an object, like every other array. Did you notice it has a `.length` property as well (that also isn't iterated)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a monster. It's just a JS object like any other array. Adding properties to a JS array is not a no no... You can. One good reason is to simple carry a state in a contained manner within the array. Functionally this is correct in a very loosely typed language like JS. If you chose to do this, then you also have to take precautions in order not to be bewildered in a `for in` loop, for instance.